# How to get current element in VirtualizedList

Tags: react-native

I want to implement a story type system in my React Native app, but it is not working as expected. I also googled and found some stories component in React-Native but none of them are implmenting Video in it. Here is my code:
**StoryItem.js**

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Pressable, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import Avtar from '../Avtar';
import Image from '../Image';
import s from '../../assets/styling';
import Loader from '../Loading';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';
import {LinearGradient} from 'react-native-svg';
import Animated, {EasingNode} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import InViewPort from '@coffeebeanslabs/react-native-inviewport';//

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

const ProgressBar = ({progress, barWidth}) => {
  return (
    <Progress.Bar
      progress={progress}
      width={barWidth}
      borderWidth={0}
      unfilledColor={'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)'}
      height={2.5}
    />
  );
};

class StoryItem extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let {story} = this.props;
    let currentStories = story?.stories;
    this.mounted = true;
    const storiesProgress = Array.from(currentStories, this._mapper);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      storyLength: currentStories?.length,
      currStoryIndex: 0,
      storyPercent: 0,
      totalDuration: 1,
      isStoryFinished: storiesProgress,
      storyDuration: 150,
      animOpacity: new Animated.Value(1),
      isStoryChanged: false,
    };
  }

  _mapper = (e, index) => {
    return {isFilled: 0};
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    let {storyPercent, totalDuration} = this.state;
    let _storyPercent = prevState.storyPercent;
    let _isStoryProgressChange = _storyPercent !== storyPercent;
    if (_isStoryProgressChange) {
      if (storyPercent >= totalDuration) {
        this._nextStory();
      }
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.mounted = false;
  }

  _onVideoLoad = e => {
    if (e?.duration) {
      this.updateState({
        totalDuration: e?.duration,
        loading: false,
      });
      this.interval = setInterval(() => this._updatePercentage(), 100);
    }
  };

  _onImageLoad = e => {
    console.log('Image is loaded....');
    if (e?.nativeEvent.width) {
      this.updateState({totalDuration: 1, loading: false});
      this.interval = setInterval(() => this._updatePercentage('image'), 100);
    }
  };

  _onBuffer = ({isBuffering}) => {
    if (isBuffering) {
      this.updateState({loading: true});
    }
  };

  _nextStory = () => {
    let {currStoryIndex, storyLength} = this.state;
    let {onStoryEnd} = this.props;
    if (currStoryIndex !== storyLength - 1) {
      let isStoryFinished = [...this.state?.isStoryFinished];
      isStoryFinished[currStoryIndex] = {isFinshed: 1};
      this.updateState({
        storyPercent: 0,
        currStoryIndex: currStoryIndex + 1,
        isStoryFinished,
      });
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      return;
    } else {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      if (onStoryEnd && typeof onStoryEnd === 'function') {
        onStoryEnd();
      }
      return;
    }
  };

  _prevStory = () => {
    let {currStoryIndex} = this.state;
    let {onStoryEnd} = this.props;
    if (currStoryIndex !== 0) {
      let isStoryFinished = [...this.state?.isStoryFinished];
      isStoryFinished[currStoryIndex] = {isFinshed: 0};
      this.updateState({
        storyPercent: 0,
        currStoryIndex: currStoryIndex - 1,
        isStoryFinished,
      });
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      return;
    } else {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      if (onStoryEnd && typeof onStoryEnd === 'function') {
        onStoryEnd();
      }
      return;
    }
  };

  _updatePercentage = type => {
    let {storyPercent, totalDuration, storyDuration, loading} = this.state;
    if (loading) {
      return;
    }
    if (type === 'video') {
      //Logics for video....
    } else {
      //Logic for image...
      const percentChange = totalDuration / storyDuration;
      this.updateState({
        storyPercent: storyPercent + percentChange,
      });
    }
  };

  updateState = (obj, callback) => {
    if (this.mounted) {
      this.setState(obj, callback);
    }
  };

  _onLongPress = () => {
    let {animOpacity} = this.state;
    this.updateState({loading: true});
    Animated.timing(animOpacity, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 300,
      easing: EasingNode.linear,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };

  _onInputFocus = () => {
    this.updateState({loading: true});
  };

  _onInputBlur = () => {
    this.updateState({loading: false});
  };

  _onPressRelease = () => {
    let {animOpacity} = this.state;
    this.updateState({loading: true});
    Animated.timing(animOpacity, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 300,
      easing: EasingNode.bounce,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
    this.updateState({loading: false});
  };

  _onPress = ({nativeEvent}) => {
    let {locationX} = nativeEvent;
    const isRight = locationX > width / 2;
    if (isRight) {
      this._nextStory();
    } else {
      this._prevStory();
    }
  };

  render() {
    let {story, stories, viewableItemIndex} = this.props;
    let {currStoryIndex, loading, storyPercent, isStoryFinished, animOpacity} =
      this.state;
    let currentStories = stories[viewableItemIndex]?.stories;
    let {type, url} = currentStories;
    let barWidth = width / currentStories.length - 8;

    return (
      <Pressable
        style={[s.bgBlack, {width, height}]}
        onLongPress={this._onLongPress}
        onPressOut={this._onPressRelease}
        onPress={this._onPress}>
        {/* <InViewPort onChange={this._onViewportChange}> */}
        {type === 'video' ? (
          <Video
            source={{
              uri: url,
            }}
            style={s.absoluteFillObject}
            resizeMode={'cover'}
            fullscreen={false}
            onError={event => {
              console.log('Error => ', event);
            }}
            onBuffer={this._onBuffer}
            onVideoBuffer={e => {
              console.log('on video buffer -> ', e);
            }}
            onLoad={this._onVideoLoad}
          />
        ) : (
          <Image
            source={url}
            style={s.absoluteFillObject}
            onLoad={this._onImageLoad}
            onProgress={e =>
              console.log(e.nativeEvent.loaded / e.nativeEvent.total)
            }
          />
        )}
        {loading && <Loader />}
        <Animated.View style={[s.flex1, {opacity: animOpacity}]}>
          <Pressable
            style={[
              s.flex1,
              s.flexRow,
              s.jsb,
              s.ac,
              s.absolute,
              s.m15,
              s.mt30,
              s.pt15,
            ]}>
            <Avtar url={story?.avtar} />
            <Text style={[s.textBold, s.textWhite, s.ms10]}>{story?.name}</Text>
            <Text style={[s.textBold, s.textLightGray, s.ms10, s.opacity]}>
              3h
            </Text>
          </Pressable>
          <LinearGradient
            colors={['rgba(0,0,0,1)', 'rgba(196, 196, 196, 0)']}
            style={[
              s.flex1,
              s.ps5,
              s.pe5,
              s.absolute,
              s.h130,
              s.w100p,
              s.pt20,
              s.mt20,
            ]}
          />
          <View
            style={[
              s.flex1,
              s.w100p,
              s.flexRow,
              s.jsb,
              s.ac,
              s.absolute,
              s.pt20,
              s.mt20,
              s.mb10,
              s.ps5,
              s.pe5,
            ]}>
            {currentStories.map((item, index) => {
              let isStoryViewed = currStoryIndex === index;
              let itemProgress = isStoryFinished[index]?.isFinshed;
              return (
                <ProgressBar
                  progress={isStoryViewed ? storyPercent : itemProgress}
                  barWidth={barWidth}
                  key={index}
                />
              );
            })}
          </View>
          <View
            style={[
              s.flex1,
              s.flexRow,
              s.absolute,
              s.bottom0,
              s.pb20,
              s.mb20,
              s.jsb,
              s.ac,
              s.ms10,
              s.me10,
            ]}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Type your text here"
              style={[s.w90p, s.br30, s.b2, s.h36, s.bColor_white, s.p10]}
              placeholderTextColor={'#ffff'}
              onFocus={this._onInputFocus}
              onBlur={this._onInputBlur}
            />
            <Icon name="paper-plane-outline" size={30} color={'#FFFFFF'} />
          </View>
        </Animated.View>
        {/* </InViewPort> */}
      </Pressable>
    );
  }
}

export default StoryItem;
```

**StoryList.js**

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {Dimensions, VirtualizedList} from 'react-native';
import s from '../../assets/styling';
import StoryItem from './item';

const {height} = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class StoryViewer extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.mounted = true;
    this.scrollRef = React.createRef(null);
    let {viewableItemIndex} = this.props;
    this.state = {
      viewableItemIndex: viewableItemIndex,
      ready: false,
    };
  }

  viewabilityConfig = {
    minimumViewTime: 100,
    viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 100,
    waitForInteraction: true,
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
  }

  _onStoryEnd = () => {};

  _itemCount = () => {
    let {stories} = this.props;
    return stories.length;
  };

  _itemRenderer = ({item}) => {
    let {viewableItemIndex} = this.state;
    let {stories} = this.props;
    let story = item;
    return (
      <StoryItem {...{story}} {...{viewableItemIndex}} stories={stories} />
    );
  };

  _onScrollFail = info => {
    const wait = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
    wait.then(() => {
      this.flatList.current?.scrollToIndex({
        index: info?.index,
        animated: false,
      });
    });
  };

  _onViewableItemChange = ({viewableItems, changed}) => {
    if (viewableItems[0]?.index) {
      this.updateState({viewableItemIndex: viewableItems[0]?.index});
    }
  };

  updateState = (obj, callback) => {
    if (this.mounted) {
      this.setState(obj, callback);
    }
  };

  render() {
    let {stories, currentStoryIndex} = this.props;
    return (
      <VirtualizedList
        renderItem={this._itemRenderer}
        data={stories}
        getItemCount={this._itemCount}
        getItem={(item, index) => item[index]}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        decelerationRate={'fast'}
        snapToInterval={height}
        initialScrollIndex={currentStoryIndex}
        disableIntervalMomentum
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        removeClippedSubviews
        windowSize={4}
        scrollsToTop={false}
        initialNumToRender={5}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={3}
        onViewableItemsChanged={this._onViewableItemChange}
        onScrollToIndexFailed={this._onScrollFail}
        viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}
        extraData={this.state}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The code works fine, if I only implement Image, but videos are not working.

Comment: Did you try this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/@blackbox-vision/react-native-live-stories

Comment: Yes, I tried to implement the above mentioned package, but it contains too much bugs and also relies on third party packages.